# Wait for gps location?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a new application ,i am using async task loader to make a query to the database before that i need to wait till location is retrieved from the gps ,is there any way we can pause async task loader work till it location information is retrieved without affecting its efficiency ?

Comment: "i need to wait till location is retrieved from the gps" -- what happens if the user never gets a GPS fix?

Comment: Use a scheduled task with a timeout... if the GPS is not ready in, let's say 30 seconds then throw an exception